# Style Select Element with same style as the selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to style a select element that is created in php.  The select code is very simple and I can style the text color of the drop down.  But this doesn't style the select element when a option is selected.  Also this code doesn't work on Safari at all.

Code:

```
<div class="theme">
<select class="theme" name="select_theme">
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</select>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.theme {
    width: 200px;
}
.theme select {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: rgba(200,200,200,0.8);
}
.theme select option[value="red"] {
   color: red;
}
.theme select option[value="green"] {
    color: green;
}
.theme select option[value="blue"] {
    color: blue;
}
```

1. How do I style the default select so that it matches the option style rule?
2. How to get this to work on Safari?  Possibly IE I haven't checked it yet no Windows system ATM.
3. Is there a way to get these rules to display an image as well?  I've tried a few things but seems it requires Javascript which I try to avoid when I can.

I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uCmSR/1/) to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way you can accomplish this without JavaScript:

```
$('select.theme').change(function () {
    $(this).css('color', $(this).find('option:selected').css('color'));
}).change();
```

Here's your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uCmSR/2/

Comment: A quick test found that it works on webkit, but Firefox only changes to white no matter what value is selected.  Any ideas why?  (Why I usually shy from JS doing style it can get very frustrating tracking down all the browser quirks.)

Comment: @MarkFinch - It seems Firefox always reports the `color` of an `option` as white. If you really need this, you should add the color to your `option`s as a data attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I am going to wait a day or two to see if anyone else comes up with a way of doing it in CSS if not then I will accept your answer.  I might fully develop this function with JS.  I don't know if there is a browser bug or just not part of the CSS spec but it seems the selected element should inherit by default the attributes of the option.

Comment: It seems Javascript is the only method, do you know of an example using the data attribute to color the select and option elements?  Or if it isn't too much to ask can you update your fiddle?